# Edit Rigify Rig after Generation

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

This is my first time using blender and rigify for animation.
I thought it was a good idea to use the wolf rig as base for a dragon. im almost happy with it but i have some troubles with the neck.

My first problem is: I cant move the position of the first neck bone. When i try to move it a bit on the y-axis in edit mode the Def Spine and some other bones get terriby sterched in object and pose mode even without a skinned mesh.
(reset everything with alt-r /alt-g doesnt work but the rest position looks fine and allying this as the rest position also messes up everything.)

Second problem: i think rigify uses the neck bones for some sort of ik but i would like to use normal fk with simple child and parent relationships (because the model has a bended long neck and i need to be able to rotate the bones against eachother) .  but i couldnt figure out how to get rid of this.
even if i try to adjust the metarig before generating the ik gets created even though i created the bones myself and set them to the bone type basic copy and changed their names or the script gets destroyed and i cant generate a rig.

like i said im new so every useful information is appreaciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i just created a new rig for the head and connected it to the alredy generated rigify rig.